# Can't communicate iOS HTTP with Laravel 5.3 on local server

Tags: laravel, alamofire

I have made successful HTTP POST requests with [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/) to my personal online server with a basic PHP script but now I am using PHP framework [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3) and I can't seem to make a successful request to my local environment.

I am running a Laravel web application on Homestead virtual server on "192.168.10.10" which translates to [mysite].dev and works fine over a browser but I cannot seem to make a successful connection via X-code (8) and Swift (3) using the Alamofire networking library.

Can anyone offer me some advice or share some resources please?

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "name": nameTextField.text,
        "username": usernameTextField.text,
        "email": emailTextField.text,
        "password": passwordTextField.text
    ]


    Alamofire.request("http://[mysite].dev/register.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

        debugPrint("All Response Info: \(response)") 
         // FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 \"The request timed out.\"

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: So the request worked for another server and, without changing anything in the client, just the server address to point to your current server (this one using Laravel), it stopped working? Is that it?

Comment: Hi Felipe, no I am talking about 2 different servers and clients, I just wanted to confirm that I have made successful Alamofire requests before so I'm not completely new to networking with Alamofire. But new to networking between Alamofire and Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the laravel project to allow CORS?, here are the instructions: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors, good luck. Bests! ;)